# How to uninstall IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I cannot disable/remove IIS component also its child components.

[image]

How to uninstall IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016?

Comment: is the problem still existing? because IIS could required by other services like AD-Services

Answer (score 2):

Open PowerShell as Administrator, run commands

```
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Default-Doc
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Dir-Browsing
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Http-Errors
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Static-Content
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Http-Logging
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Request-Monitor
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Stat-Compression
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Filtering
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Windows-Auth
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Net-Ext45
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-ISAPI-Ext
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-ISAPI-Filter
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Console
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Metabase
```

Then Server Manager: Manage \ Remove Roles and Features

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove them because you opened the "Add Roles and Features" wizard. You need to open the "Remove Roles and Features" one...

[image]

Comment: I cannot use this features when remove, it was disabled strangely.